# Converting TfidfVectorizer's fit_transform variable to an array (.toarray()) makes everything zero?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm experimenting with tfidf with a sample dataset, and everything is working fine up until I convert my fit-transofrm variable to an array.
I am trying to view my "features" after using tfidf, and the values make sense when i print it. However, when i print it as an array, then all values become zero for some reason.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

filename = 'test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, min_df=5, norm='l2', encoding='latin-1', ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
features = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Comments.astype('U'))
label_map = {'Y': 1, 'N': 0}
labels = df.Non_Comp_IND.map(label_map)
print(features)
```

the result from the last line of the print statement is this:

```
(0, 6433)   0.1354882591295125
  (0, 18430)    0.057506963357173674
  (0, 16902)    0.0887002305355381
  (0, 17540)    0.46335455366392575
  (0, 19175)    0.2159334960329325
  (0, 16590)    0.15130364285967984
(0, 9104)   0.15285500637985408
  (0, 16595)    0.1890315464705662
  : :
(24455, 14202)  0.17695626302265938
  (24455, 6699) 0.2309569171857742
  (24455, 10308)    0.2279428326498053
  (24455, 16678)    0.2343740044032419
  (24455, 12122)    0.23831874209561996
  (24455, 18919)    0.23831874209561996
```

The numbers above make sense, but when I change the line to print it in an array format `print(features.toarray())`, this is what i get:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

I did check each value, for example `features.toarray()[3][10]` , they are all `0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I am testing it incorrectly, there are actually some values after knowing more about the tf-idf matrix, each word has its own column, so only the words that are unhique in the document will have a value in the matrix, they are NOT all zeros.